# PowerBI AND/OR function between 3 tables

Tags: powerbi

I have the following table created in a Dashboard:

```
Name     Exist in AD     Exist in EDR    Exist in ASDF
  A         TRUE             TRUE            TRUE
  B         TRUE             TRUE            TRUE
  C         FALSE            FALSE           TRUE
```

Every field cames from a different tables. I would like to calculate in a dashboard a new column with the following result:

New Column = AND (Exist in AD,(OR(Exist in EDR,Exist in ASDF))

Comment: how you are getting Exist in AD? if measure, you can show the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following DAX:

```
New Column =
var nameVar = table[Name]
var existAD = CONTAINS(AD, AD[columnNameAD], nameVar)
var existEDR = CONTAINS(EDR, EDR[columnNameEDR], nameVar)
var existASDF = CONTAINS(ASDF, ASDF[columnNameASDF], nameVar)
return existAD && (existsEDR || existsASDF)
```

Caintais returns true if Name of the variable in the Row exists in other table in that column.
At the end I put it logic together..